# Why does the illustration below just show $J = 1/2$ and $J = 3/2$ for $n = 2$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, spin-orbit

for example $p^4$ on $n = 2$, $l = 1$ would have $J = 2$ as $S = 1$ and $L = 1$. However there are just two not 4 levels for $J$ depicted here

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think you meant S=1/2 not 1

Comment: @Mauricio I think it is S = 1, since there is just one paired electron whose spin is compensated and two unpaired whose spins s = 1/2 add up to S = 1. or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, thank you for explaining. Maybe you should add more context to your question. Mainly, what is the system you are studying. You can always edit the post to add further details.